# How to fix this warning of wxPyDeprecationWarning in wxPython module?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, pypubsub

a deprecating warning in wxPython lib is as follows:
wxPyDeprecationWarning: wx.lib.pubsub has been deprecated, plese migrate your code to use pypubsub, available on PyPI.

python 3.7.2 and pycharm IDE

Comment: Did you try `pip3 install pypubsub`  or `import pubsub`

Answer (score 3):

`wx.lib.pubsub` is now deprecated in wxPython. You will need to install [PyPubSub](https://pypi.org/project/PyPubSub/) now. The PyPubSub package is actually what `wx.lib.pubsub` was based on, so the implementation will be almost the same. You can read its documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyPubSub/).

To install PyPubSub, use pip:

```
 pip install PyPubSub
```

Then replace `from wx.lib.pubsub import pub` with `from pubsub import pub`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change references to `wx.lib.pubsub` to `pubsub`
So for example:

```
# Changing the following line
#from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

# to the line below is all that is required
from pubsub import pub
```

Comment: @siliconMaigc If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted (check mark in the top left). Doing this allows focussing on questions with no accepted answers.